# Why does this make the server time out?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm trying to run

```
SELECT id, max(event_date) dt
FROM worker
LEFT JOIN events ON id = attendee
WHERE worker.type='CON'
GROUP BY id;
```

but the query takes much too long.  Is there a way to make this faster?

`worker` and `events` are somewhat large (10,000 records) tables joined one-to-many.  (Most workers have 0 associated events, but some have up to 10 or so.)  But I wouldn't think this is so large that the query would fail.  Ideas?

Comment: Run explain and show the execution plan. Make sure you have index on events.attendee. Assuming that id is primary key, make sure you have index on worker.type

Answer (score 0):

Posting the exact table schemas would allow for better analysis.

I'm guessing attendee and type are not indexed.

Try prefixing your query with "explain" (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain-output.html) for details on the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Without a schema, this is forced to be a guess.  But does the `events` table have both an `id` field and an `attendee` field?

Does being more explicit in your query help?

```
SELECT worker.id, max(events.event_date) dt
FROM worker
LEFT JOIN events ON worker.id = events.attendee
WHERE worker.type='CON'
GROUP BY worker.id;
```

*(I've had to assume which tables each field associates to.)*